# Как сделать и запустить бота в дискорде

Tags: бот, discord

Как сделать и запустить бота в дискорде который будет брать токены (у меня их очень много) и с них заходить на определенный сервер.

То есть нужно сделать так чтобы бот брал токен , заходил на аккаунт и на сервер и был онлайн на сервере.

Comment: тоесть нужно сделать так чтобы бот брал токен , заходил на аккаунт и на сервер и был онлайн на сервере

Answer (score 0):

качаешь vs code -> code.visualstudio.com
так-же python -> python.org
и библиотеку discord которую надо скачать через терминал

как это сделать -> [image: Клик]

После скачивания Vs code и Python и библиотеки disccord

Создаешь проект в программе и создаешь там  файл bot.py или можешь назвать как тебе удобно

Но что-бы работал бот нужно скачать библиотеку discord и так-же взять токен  бота на сайте [discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/docs/game-sdk/applications)  там разобраться не сложно

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/') создаем префикс "/"

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
await ctx.send('Привет, я бот для Discord!') # отправка сообщения "Привет, я бот для Discord!" в канал

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
await ctx.send('Pong!') # отправка сообщения "Pong!" в канал

bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN') # тут токен бота

Comment: нет, смотри, мне нужно чтобы аккаунты заходили на сервера в дискорде а именно накрутка тоесть я беру токен аккаунта и мне нужно сделать чтобы этот токен зашел на сервер , как это сделать просто аккаунтов много

Comment: @user548774, что?